# Timer in Eclipse for Android Game

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timer

I'm making this android game of mine for our Programming 3 course. And I don't have any idea how can I make a timer that will not stop until the user finished all the 3 levels of the game? Please help me :(

Comment: you just want the time that it took to complete a level? just take the `end time` - the `start time`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz How can I implement that?

Answer (score 2):

You can start the time in a service. So it will continue to run in the background irresoective of anythings. After completing 3 levels you can stop the timer by stopping the service.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "in a service" ?

Comment: @Sushil that would be way to expensive to do. The best way would be to store the "start time" and then just calculate the time passed from the "start time" to "now".